# Why this const is undefined when it should be?

Tags: javascript

I have a form that gets the calculation of the insurance of a vehicle, I have reduced the code to only show the problem that I have (so if you see it incomplete it is because I reduced it).

My problem is that I have two input type radio, this for the user to choose one of two options and the problem comes when I try to pass the value of that constant from the "quoteInsurance" function to the prototype "UI.prototype.showResult", when I read other constants like *"year"*, *"brand"*, this one gets the result, but when I do it with "selectedType" then it says the value is undefined.

```js
//Variables
const form = document.querySelector("#cotizar-seguro");


//eventlisteners
eventlisteners();
function eventlisteners(){

    form.addEventListener("submit", quoteInsurance);
}



//functions

//constructors
function Insurance(brand, year, type) {
    this.brand = brand;
    this.year = year;
    this.type = type;
};


//Constructor object for the UI
function UI() {};


//prototype to show in the html the result of the calculation and the info of the Auto

UI.prototype.showResult = (insurance) => {
    const {brand, year, selectedType} = insurance;
    console.log(brand);
    console.log(selectedType);
};    

//instance ui

const ui = new UI();


function quoteInsurance(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    
    //read selected brand
    const brand = document.querySelector("#marca").value;

    //read selected year
    const year = document.querySelector("#year").value;

    //read selected type
    const selectedType = document.querySelector('input[name="tipo"]:checked').value;
 

    //Initialize insurance
    const insurance = new Insurance(brand, year, selectedType);

    //we use the prototype to show result
    ui.showResult(insurance);
    
};
```

```css
body {
    background: #e96443;  /* fallback for old browsers */
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(to right, #904e95, #e96443);  /* Chrome 10-25, Safari 5.1-6 */
    background: linear-gradient(to right, #904e95, #e96443); 
}
.btn.btn-raised.btn-primary {
    background-color: #00838F!important;
    font-size: 16px;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 15px;
}
.error {
    background-color: #FBE9E7;
    border: 1px solid #F4511E;
    padding: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    text-align: center;
    color: #F4511E;
}
.correcto {
    background-color: rgb(211, 249, 187);
    border: 1px solid rgb(50, 167, 0);
    padding: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    text-align: center;
    color: rgb(4, 150, 50);
}
.error p {
    margin:0;
}
#contenido {
    margin-top: 60px;
    background-color: white;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 21px 46px -15px rgba(0,0,0,1);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 21px 46px -15px rgba(0,0,0,1);
    box-shadow: 0px 21px 46px -15px rgba(0,0,0,1);
}
.contenido-formulario {
    margin-top: 30px;
}
#cargando {
    text-align: center;
}
#cargando img {
    display: none;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
#resultado  {
    margin-bottom: 40px;
}
#resultado div {
    border: 1px solid #26C6DA;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 0  0 20px 0;
}
#resultado div p {
    margin-bottom: 0;
}
#resultado div p.header {
    background-color: #26C6DA;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    color:white;
    padding: 10px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.spinner {
    margin: 50px auto;
    width: 50px;
    height: 40px;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 10px;
  }
  
  .spinner > div {
    background-color: #26C6DA;
    height: 100%;
    width: 6px;
    display: inline-block;
    
    -webkit-animation: sk-stretchdelay 1.2s infinite ease-in-out;
    animation: sk-stretchdelay 1.2s infinite ease-in-out;
  }
  
  .spinner .rect2 {
    -webkit-animation-delay: -1.1s;
    animation-delay: -1.1s;
  }
  
  .spinner .rect3 {
    -webkit-animation-delay: -1.0s;
    animation-delay: -1.0s;
  }
  
  .spinner .rect4 {
    -webkit-animation-delay: -0.9s;
    animation-delay: -0.9s;
  }
  
  .spinner .rect5 {
    -webkit-animation-delay: -0.8s;
    animation-delay: -0.8s;
  }
  
  @-webkit-keyframes sk-stretchdelay {
    0%, 40%, 100% { -webkit-transform: scaleY(0.4) }  
    20% { -webkit-transform: scaleY(1.0) }
  }
  
  @keyframes sk-stretchdelay {
    0%, 40%, 100% { 
      transform: scaleY(0.4);
      -webkit-transform: scaleY(0.4);
    }  20% { 
      transform: scaleY(1.0);
      -webkit-transform: scaleY(1.0);
    }
  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/custom.css">
  </head>
  <body>
<div class="container mx-auto">
      <div id="contenido" class="pb-10">
            <header class="bg-teal-500 text-white py-3 font-bold uppercase">
                <h1 class="text-center">Cotiza tu seguro de Auto</h1>
            </header>
                <form class="mt-10 max-w-lg mx-auto" action="#" id="cotizar-seguro">
                        <div class="flex items-center mb-5">
                            <label 
                              class="font-bold  uppercase mr-2 w-20"
                              for="marca"
                            >Marca:</label>
                            <select class="flex-1 bg-gray-100 p-3 appearance-none" id="marca">
                                <option value="">- Seleccionar -</option>
                                <option value="1">Americano</option>
                                <option value="2">Asiatico</option>
                                <option value="3">Europeo</option>
                            </select>
                        </div>
                        <div class="flex items-center mb-5">
                              <label 
                                class="font-bold  uppercase mr-2 w-20"
                                for="year"
                              >Año:</label>
                              <select  class="flex-1 bg-gray-100 p-3 appearance-none" id="year">
                                <option value="2022">2022</option>
                              </select>
                        </div>
                        <fieldset>
                              <legend  class="font-bold  uppercase text-2xl text-center w-full">Tipo Seguro</legend>

                              <div class="flex justify-around mt-5">
                                  <div>
                                      <label class="font-bold  uppercase mr-2">Básico</label>
                                          <input type="radio" name="tipo" value="basico" checked>
                                      </label>
                                  </div>
                                  <div>
                                      <label class="font-bold  uppercase mr-2">Completo</label>
                                          <input type="radio" name="tipo" value="completo">
                                      </label>
                                  </div>
                              </div>
                      </fieldset>

                  <div id="cargando" class="hidden">
                        <div class="spinner">
                          <div class="rect1"></div>
                          <div class="rect2"></div>
                          <div class="rect3"></div>
                          <div class="rect4"></div>
                          <div class="rect5"></div>
                      </div>
                  </div>
                  <div id="resultado"></div>
                  <div class="flex  justify-center py-4">
                      <button 
                        type="submit" 
                        class="mx-auto bg-teal-500 hover:bg-teal-700 text-white font-bold py-2 px-20 rounded"
                        >Cotizar Seguro
                    </button>
                  </div>
 
                </form> 
      </div> <!--#contenido-->
</div>

  <script src="js/app.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you include only the code needed to reproduce the issue?  It will help ensure your question gets the attention it deserves and help future SO users.  Most people skip 'full projects'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change the `selectedType` to `type`

```
UI.prototype.showResult = (insurance) => {
    const {brand, year, type} = insurance;
    console.log(brand);
    console.log(type);
};
```

Read more about destructing assignment..
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment

Answer (score 1):

You define `type` (not `selectedType`) in `Insurance`

```
function Insurance(brand, year, type) {
    this.brand = brand;
    this.year = year;
    this.type = type;
};
```

When you instantiate `Insurance`, the 3rd param from `selectedType` is assigned to `type`

```
const insurance = new Insurance(brand, year, selectedType);
```

```js
//Variables
const form = document.querySelector("#cotizar-seguro");


//eventlisteners
eventlisteners();
function eventlisteners(){

    form.addEventListener("submit", quoteInsurance);
}



//functions

//constructors
function Insurance(brand, year, type) {
    this.brand = brand;
    this.year = year;
    this.type = type;
};


//Constructor object for the UI
function UI() {};


//prototype to show in the html the result of the calculation and the info of the Auto

UI.prototype.showResult = (insurance) => {
    const {brand, year, type} = insurance;
    console.log(brand);
    console.log(type); //it should be `type` (not `selectedType`)
};    

//instance ui

const ui = new UI();


function quoteInsurance(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    
    //read selected brand
    const brand = document.querySelector("#marca").value;

    //read selected year
    const year = document.querySelector("#year").value;

    //read selected type
    const selectedType = document.querySelector('input[name="tipo"]:checked').value;
 

    //Initialize insurance
    const insurance = new Insurance(brand, year, selectedType);

    //we use the prototype to show result
    ui.showResult(insurance);
    
};
```

```css
body {
    background: #e96443;  /* fallback for old browsers */
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(to right, #904e95, #e96443);  /* Chrome 10-25, Safari 5.1-6 */
    background: linear-gradient(to right, #904e95, #e96443); 
}
.btn.btn-raised.btn-primary {
    background-color: #00838F!important;
    font-size: 16px;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 15px;
}
.error {
    background-color: #FBE9E7;
    border: 1px solid #F4511E;
    padding: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    text-align: center;
    color: #F4511E;
}
.correcto {
    background-color: rgb(211, 249, 187);
    border: 1px solid rgb(50, 167, 0);
    padding: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    text-align: center;
    color: rgb(4, 150, 50);
}
.error p {
    margin:0;
}
#contenido {
    margin-top: 60px;
    background-color: white;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 21px 46px -15px rgba(0,0,0,1);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 21px 46px -15px rgba(0,0,0,1);
    box-shadow: 0px 21px 46px -15px rgba(0,0,0,1);
}
.contenido-formulario {
    margin-top: 30px;
}
#cargando {
    text-align: center;
}
#cargando img {
    display: none;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
#resultado  {
    margin-bottom: 40px;
}
#resultado div {
    border: 1px solid #26C6DA;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 0  0 20px 0;
}
#resultado div p {
    margin-bottom: 0;
}
#resultado div p.header {
    background-color: #26C6DA;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    color:white;
    padding: 10px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.spinner {
    margin: 50px auto;
    width: 50px;
    height: 40px;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 10px;
  }
  
  .spinner > div {
    background-color: #26C6DA;
    height: 100%;
    width: 6px;
    display: inline-block;
    
    -webkit-animation: sk-stretchdelay 1.2s infinite ease-in-out;
    animation: sk-stretchdelay 1.2s infinite ease-in-out;
  }
  
  .spinner .rect2 {
    -webkit-animation-delay: -1.1s;
    animation-delay: -1.1s;
  }
  
  .spinner .rect3 {
    -webkit-animation-delay: -1.0s;
    animation-delay: -1.0s;
  }
  
  .spinner .rect4 {
    -webkit-animation-delay: -0.9s;
    animation-delay: -0.9s;
  }
  
  .spinner .rect5 {
    -webkit-animation-delay: -0.8s;
    animation-delay: -0.8s;
  }
  
  @-webkit-keyframes sk-stretchdelay {
    0%, 40%, 100% { -webkit-transform: scaleY(0.4) }  
    20% { -webkit-transform: scaleY(1.0) }
  }
  
  @keyframes sk-stretchdelay {
    0%, 40%, 100% { 
      transform: scaleY(0.4);
      -webkit-transform: scaleY(0.4);
    }  20% { 
      transform: scaleY(1.0);
      -webkit-transform: scaleY(1.0);
    }
  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/custom.css">
  </head>
  <body>
<div class="container mx-auto">
      <div id="contenido" class="pb-10">
            <header class="bg-teal-500 text-white py-3 font-bold uppercase">
                <h1 class="text-center">Cotiza tu seguro de Auto</h1>
            </header>
                <form class="mt-10 max-w-lg mx-auto" action="#" id="cotizar-seguro">
                        <div class="flex items-center mb-5">
                            <label 
                              class="font-bold  uppercase mr-2 w-20"
                              for="marca"
                            >Marca:</label>
                            <select class="flex-1 bg-gray-100 p-3 appearance-none" id="marca">
                                <option value="">- Seleccionar -</option>
                                <option value="1">Americano</option>
                                <option value="2">Asiatico</option>
                                <option value="3">Europeo</option>
                            </select>
                        </div>
                        <div class="flex items-center mb-5">
                              <label 
                                class="font-bold  uppercase mr-2 w-20"
                                for="year"
                              >Año:</label>
                              <select  class="flex-1 bg-gray-100 p-3 appearance-none" id="year">
                                <option value="2022">2022</option>
                              </select>
                        </div>
                        <fieldset>
                              <legend  class="font-bold  uppercase text-2xl text-center w-full">Tipo Seguro</legend>

                              <div class="flex justify-around mt-5">
                                  <div>
                                      <label class="font-bold  uppercase mr-2">Básico</label>
                                          <input type="radio" name="tipo" value="basico" checked>
                                      </label>
                                  </div>
                                  <div>
                                      <label class="font-bold  uppercase mr-2">Completo</label>
                                          <input type="radio" name="tipo" value="completo">
                                      </label>
                                  </div>
                              </div>
                      </fieldset>

                  <div id="cargando" class="hidden">
                        <div class="spinner">
                          <div class="rect1"></div>
                          <div class="rect2"></div>
                          <div class="rect3"></div>
                          <div class="rect4"></div>
                          <div class="rect5"></div>
                      </div>
                  </div>
                  <div id="resultado"></div>
                  <div class="flex  justify-center py-4">
                      <button 
                        type="submit" 
                        class="mx-auto bg-teal-500 hover:bg-teal-700 text-white font-bold py-2 px-20 rounded"
                        >Cotizar Seguro
                    </button>
                  </div>
 
                </form> 
      </div> <!--#contenido-->
</div>

  <script src="js/app.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason it is undefined is because in the function `Interface`, `selectedType` is cast to a variable with a different name, `type`. If you change `selectedType` to `type` in `UI.prototype.showResult` it works as expected as can be seen here:

```js
//Variables
const form = document.querySelector("#cotizar-seguro");


//eventlisteners
eventlisteners();

function eventlisteners() {

  form.addEventListener("submit", quoteInsurance);
}



//functions

//constructors
function Insurance(brand, year, type) {
  this.brand = brand;
  this.year = year;
  this.type = type;
};


//Constructor object for the UI
function UI() {};


//prototype to show in the html the result of the calculation and the info of the Auto

UI.prototype.showResult = (insurance) => {
  const {
    brand,
    year,
    type
  } = insurance;
  console.log(brand);
  console.log(type);
};

//instance ui

const ui = new UI();


function quoteInsurance(e) {
  e.preventDefault();

  //read selected brand
  const brand = document.querySelector("#marca").value;

  //read selected year
  const year = document.querySelector("#year").value;

  //read selected type
  const selectedType = document.querySelector('input[name="tipo"]:checked').value;


  //Initialize insurance
  const insurance = new Insurance(brand, year, selectedType);

  //we use the prototype to show result
  ui.showResult(insurance);

};
```

```css
body {
  background: #e96443;
  /* fallback for old browsers */
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(to right, #904e95, #e96443);
  /* Chrome 10-25, Safari 5.1-6 */
  background: linear-gradient(to right, #904e95, #e96443);
}

.btn.btn-raised.btn-primary {
  background-color: #00838F!important;
  font-size: 16px;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 15px;
}

.error {
  background-color: #FBE9E7;
  border: 1px solid #F4511E;
  padding: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  color: #F4511E;
}

.correcto {
  background-color: rgb(211, 249, 187);
  border: 1px solid rgb(50, 167, 0);
  padding: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  color: rgb(4, 150, 50);
}

.error p {
  margin: 0;
}

#contenido {
  margin-top: 60px;
  background-color: white;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 21px 46px -15px rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0px 21px 46px -15px rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
  box-shadow: 0px 21px 46px -15px rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
}

.contenido-formulario {
  margin-top: 30px;
}

#cargando {
  text-align: center;
}

#cargando img {
  display: none;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

#resultado {
  margin-bottom: 40px;
}

#resultado div {
  border: 1px solid #26C6DA;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 0 0 20px 0;
}

#resultado div p {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

#resultado div p.header {
  background-color: #26C6DA;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  color: white;
  padding: 10px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.spinner {
  margin: 50px auto;
  width: 50px;
  height: 40px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 10px;
}

.spinner>div {
  background-color: #26C6DA;
  height: 100%;
  width: 6px;
  display: inline-block;
  -webkit-animation: sk-stretchdelay 1.2s infinite ease-in-out;
  animation: sk-stretchdelay 1.2s infinite ease-in-out;
}

.spinner .rect2 {
  -webkit-animation-delay: -1.1s;
  animation-delay: -1.1s;
}

.spinner .rect3 {
  -webkit-animation-delay: -1.0s;
  animation-delay: -1.0s;
}

.spinner .rect4 {
  -webkit-animation-delay: -0.9s;
  animation-delay: -0.9s;
}

.spinner .rect5 {
  -webkit-animation-delay: -0.8s;
  animation-delay: -0.8s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes sk-stretchdelay {
  0%,
  40%,
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: scaleY(0.4)
  }
  20% {
    -webkit-transform: scaleY(1.0)
  }
}

@keyframes sk-stretchdelay {
  0%,
  40%,
  100% {
    transform: scaleY(0.4);
    -webkit-transform: scaleY(0.4);
  }
  20% {
    transform: scaleY(1.0);
    -webkit-transform: scaleY(1.0);
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <!-- Required meta tags -->
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">


  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/custom.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container mx-auto">
    <div id="contenido" class="pb-10">
      <header class="bg-teal-500 text-white py-3 font-bold uppercase">
        <h1 class="text-center">Cotiza tu seguro de Auto</h1>
      </header>
      <form class="mt-10 max-w-lg mx-auto" action="#" id="cotizar-seguro">
        <div class="flex items-center mb-5">
          <label class="font-bold  uppercase mr-2 w-20" for="marca">Marca:</label>
          <select class="flex-1 bg-gray-100 p-3 appearance-none" id="marca">
            <option value="">- Seleccionar -</option>
            <option value="1">Americano</option>
            <option value="2">Asiatico</option>
            <option value="3">Europeo</option>
          </select>
        </div>
        <div class="flex items-center mb-5">
          <label class="font-bold  uppercase mr-2 w-20" for="year">Año:</label>
          <select class="flex-1 bg-gray-100 p-3 appearance-none" id="year">
            <option value="2022">2022</option>
          </select>
        </div>
        <fieldset>
          <legend class="font-bold  uppercase text-2xl text-center w-full">Tipo Seguro</legend>

          <div class="flex justify-around mt-5">
            <div>
              <label class="font-bold  uppercase mr-2">Básico</label>
              <input type="radio" name="tipo" value="basico" checked>
            </div>
            <div>
              <label class="font-bold  uppercase mr-2">Completo</label>
              <input type="radio" name="tipo" value="completo">
            </div>
          </div>
        </fieldset>

        <div id="cargando" class="hidden">
          <div class="spinner">
            <div class="rect1"></div>
            <div class="rect2"></div>
            <div class="rect3"></div>
            <div class="rect4"></div>
            <div class="rect5"></div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div id="resultado"></div>
        <div class="flex  justify-center py-4">
          <button type="submit" class="mx-auto bg-teal-500 hover:bg-teal-700 text-white font-bold py-2 px-20 rounded">Cotizar Seguro
                    </button>
        </div>

      </form>
    </div>
    <!--#contenido-->
  </div>

  <script src="js/app.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com"></script>
</body>

</html>
```